# PHP $_GET file not retrieving data from a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I have PHP scripts that are trying to read data from my mysql database. The first script called news.php reads data from some of the rows in my database and displays it in summary form. It also generates a unique hyperlink for each article that someone can click on and be taken to read the full article.

This is the news.php that retrieves a summary from my database

```
<?php
    // connection string constants
    define('DSN', 'mysql:dbname=mynewsdb;host=localhost');
    define('USER', 'myadmin');
    define('PASSWORD', 'pwd2015');

    // pdo instance creation
    $pdo = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASSWORD);

    // query preparation
    $stmt = $pdo->query("
        SELECT title, introtext, id, created, created_by, catid
        FROM mynews_items
    ");

    // fetching results
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // if this returns 0 then it means no records are present
    echo count($result) . "\n";

    // the loop should print valid table
    foreach ($result as $index => $row) {
        if ($index == 0) echo '<table>';
        echo <<<HTM
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="post-date">{$row['created']}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <h2 class="blog-post-title">{$row['title']}</h2>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <p>
            {$row['introtext']}
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <p>

            <a href='read.php?id={$row['id']}'><input type="button" value="Read More" /></a>
        </p>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="blog-meta">
            <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" />
            <h4 class="blog-meta-author">{$row['created_by']}</h4>
            <span>Category: {$row['catid']}</span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
HTM;
        if ($index == (count($result)-1)) echo '</table>';
    }
```

When you click on the hyperlink generated by  `<a href='read.php?id={$row['id']}'><input type="button" value="Read More" /></a>` the read.php script should retrieve and show the full article from my database. The field storing the articles is named `fulltext`

This is the read.php file

```
      <?php
    // connection string constants
    define('DSN', 'mysql:dbname=mynewsdb;host=localhost');
    define('USER', 'myadmin');
    define('PASSWORD', 'pwd2015');

    // pdo instance creation
    $pdo = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASSWORD);

    // query preparation
    $stmt = $pdo->query("
        SELECT fulltext
        FROM mynews_items
    ");
    echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["fulltext"]);

?>
```

Can someone point out the mistake I am making on my read.php file because it loads as a blank page without any data.

**UPDATED read.php**
This is the updated file which is still returning a blank page. Can anyone point out any mistake?

```
<?php
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        if(isset($_GET['id']))

    // connection string constants
        define('DSN', 'mysql:dbname=mynewsdb;host=localhost');
        define('USER', 'myadmin');
        define('PASSWORD', 'pwd2015');

    // pdo instance creation
        $pdo = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASSWORD);

    // query preparation
    // $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT id, fulltext FROM fm16p_k2_items WHERE id='{$row['id']}'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    {
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT fulltext * FROM fm16p_k2_items WHERE id = '{$id}'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_object($sql);
}

    echo $row->fulltext;

?>
```

Comment: You didn't grab a row, change `$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT fulltext FROM mynews_items", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: I see you did not make query in read.php according to id. At first get the id and then make query according to id.

`$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT fulltext FROM mynews_items WHERE id='your id'", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: @srmilon I have updated the code but it is still returning a blank page

Comment: Could you demonstrate the updated code so that i can check it out?

Comment: @srmilon can you look at my updated read.php above and see what mistake I'm making if you can identify any?

Comment: Please *NEVER* upload your MySQL passwords to the internet like this. Make sure you change *everywhere* that uses these credentials (as once it's on here, it can't be reverted).

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thanks ..I just forgot to take them out. Thankfully its just a testing server

Comment: Also don't use `{$id}` or such syntax in SQL query, but use prepared queries, as your system is SQL Injection valnurable. Better to do something like: `$sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT fulltext FROM mynews_items WHERE id = :id"); $sql->bindParam(":id", $id);`

Comment: Please make sure you are getting the ID on read.php page by echo the `$id`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT fulltext
    FROM mynews_items WHERE id = :id");

$sql->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
$stmt = $sql->fetchAll();
```

Comment: this is not working either. Can you look at my updated read.php file and see if you can identify any mistake in my code?

Comment: if you don't want to use PDO then change $pdo = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASSWORD); to mysql_connect and mysql_select_db then why you use WHERE id = '{$id}'" instead of WHERE id = '$id'"? Also it would be great if you add table structure to you question.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked in the code above, but in the code bellow, you didn't grab a row, and you're fetching all of the `fulltext`'s, do either of these:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT fulltext FROM mynews_items", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to fetch only one row, but as Ali Idrees said, you'd need a `WHERE` clause (ie. `SELECT fulltext FROM mynews_items WHERE id = 3`), or:

```
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo $row['fulltext'];
}
```

to grab all of the fulltexts in the database and print them.

EDIT: Also, it's highly recomended that you use prepared statements:

```
$prep = $pdo->prepare("SELECT fulltext FROM mynews_items WHERE id = :id");
$prep->bindParam(":id", $id);
$prep->execute();
if($prep->fetch()){
    echo $prep['fulltext'];
}
```

Comment: this is not returning any result either

Answer (score 0):

You probably already got the answers you were looking for, but I wanted to stress that an input field inside a link is not a good thing to do. However, you can style your link to look like an input field, if you want it so.

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a `WHERE` clause when you're fetching `fulltext`